# JAP how to have primary key foreign key relation without having extra column or extra mapping table

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

[image]

**From the picture, is it possible to have QUALIFICATION_ID as foreign key of ID without extra mapping column or table?**

**TABLE --> TM_QUALIFICATIONS**  is a master table, ID is autogenerated UUID and name is String value. Value will be inserted into this table on application startup.

**TABLE --> TM_USER_QUALIFICATIONS**, one user can have multiple qualifications.

So without any other extra mapping column or table, is it possible to mark QUALIFICATION_ID as a foreign key?

Also how can I combine USER_ID and QUALIFICATION_ID to make composite primary key for TM_USER_QUALIFICATIONS table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can define foreign key relationship without having extra column or extra mapping table.

If I understood you correctly you can do something like

**TM_QUALIFICATIONS**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TM_QUALIFICATIONS")
    public class Qualifications {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private String id;

        @Column(name = "NAME")
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }
```

and to make QUALIFICATION_ID as foreign key, u write separate DDL for adding constraint.

```
@Repository
public interface UserQualificationsRepository extends CrudRepository<UserQualifications, String>{

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "ALTER TABLE TM_USER_QUALIFICATIONS ADD FOREIGN KEY (QUALIFICATION_ID) REFERENCES TM_QUALIFICATIONS(ID)", nativeQuery = true)
    public void addForeignKeyConstraint();
}
```

**TM_USER_QUALIFICATIONS**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TM_USER_QUALIFICATIONS")
@IdClass(UserQualificationPK.class)
public class UserQualifications {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "LEVEL")
    private int level = 0;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "QUALIFICATION_ID")
    private String qualificationId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }
}
```

At last for composite primary key use @IdClass annotation

```
public class UserQualificationPK implements Serializable {

    private String userId;

    private String qualificationId;

    public UserQualificationPK(String userId, String qualificationId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.qualificationId = qualificationId;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getQualificationId() {
        return qualificationId;
    }

    public void setQualificationId(String qualificationId) {
        this.qualificationId = qualificationId;
    }
}
```

In this way u can achieve your requirements. There is no relationship between TM_QUALIFICATIONS and TM_USER_QUALIFICATIONS, but your explicitly defining QUALIFICATION_ID as foreign key by native SQL.